# How to show 4 calendars using fullCalendar plugin on single page?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to show 4 different calendars on single page using full calendar plugin but I've no idea about full calendar plugin. I'm new to jQuery full calendar plugin.For example: I've 4 different ids for 4 different calendars but I want to write jquery only one time.

Comment: So what have you done, research or even tried? Have a look at this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? There are many jQuery calendar plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to show 4 calendars, you should have 4 different places to put it. I made a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/V5S7b/1/

You can see 4 different DIV's and one call for the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar, #calendar2, #calendar3, #calendar4').fullCalendar({
        //Extra thingies
    })

});
```

The extra thingies comment, is the place where you put extra parameters (if you want to use them). To be honest, i have to say you should look into some jQuery/JavaScript 101 courses because this is very basic.